# C#: Custom order arrays, with a twist:

Tags: c#

The list I have is based on checking the first 4 values to sort correctly, but I need any other value in the list that is not predefined (and does not start with CS) to be prioritized as I have commented below.  The non predefined values would likely always be anything starting with a numeric value so anything starting with 1-9 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

How can I custom sort something like this?  Should I focus on redefining anything beginning with 1-9 in a separate list, or is there something I can use that would represent "Anything not defined goes here"  Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for your help everyone, I called it a night and used excel to generate every number combination from 0-9999 starting with 0000,0001 etc as well as 000-, 001- for the 3 digit numbers that go before the oddball CS #.  The cool thing is that the program takes a second or two to crunch everything which makes it look like it is doing a lot of work!  (I suppose it is)  I may add a progress bar!  Program is now 229kb, but it works!  Sometimes you just have to break out the duct tape.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Comparer : IComparer<string>
    {

        private Dictionary<string, int> _order;

        public Comparer()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "CS01",
        "CS10",
        "CS58",
        "CS11",
        "CS71",
        "CS02",
        "CS55",
        "CS03",
        "CS70",
        "CS54",
        "CS60",
             //<---How to prioritize any value that is not predefined in list to show up here?  such as 1234-444-555
        "CS57",

    };

            _order = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                _order.Add(list[i], i);
            }
        }

        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x.Length < 4 || y.Length < 4)
                return x.CompareTo(y);

            string xPrefix = x.Substring(0, 4);
            string yPrefix = y.Substring(0, 4);

            int xSequence;
            int ySequence;
            if (_order.TryGetValue(xPrefix, out xSequence)
                && _order.TryGetValue(yPrefix, out ySequence))
            {
                return xSequence.CompareTo(ySequence);
            }
            else
            {
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("(", "");
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(")", "");
        string[] items = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Array.Sort<string>(items, 0, items.Length, new Comparer());
        textBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);

         }



}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for a "natural sort"? See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html for a discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq.  However this assumes that all your strings have CS and the rest are numbers.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("CS01");
list.Add("CS02");
list.Add("CS03");
list.Add("CS14");
list.Add("CS11");
list.Add("CS5");
list.Add("CS17");

List<string> orderList = list
    .OrderBy<string, int>(i => int.Parse(i.Replace("CS", string.Empty)))
    .ToList<string>();

// Print List
for (int i = 0; i < orderList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(orderList[i]);
}
```

Prints

```
CS01
CS02
CS03
CS5
CS11
CS14
CS17
```

If your strings are more complicated I would create another function to help parse them.  In this case this is simple sample code, and not the ideal way to parse the number from the given string.  For example if you string was CSS101 it would throw and exception because it would not be able to parse S101 to an int.  I will leave these up to you to add.

Comment: Reading your answer, I do not think it answers the question - your assume that all your strings have CS in them, and Saintjah mentions that he is looking to identify strings that do **not** begin with CS.

Comment: I edited my question to help clarify so David was correct at that time, it was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a small custom class which implements [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) to do the sort for you. You return -1 to denote that the first argument is smaller than the second, 1 to denote it's larger and 0 to define equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly improve upon this solution, but I believe it implements the IComparer Nick mentioned.

```
public class Comparer : IComparer<string>
    {

      private Dictionary<string, int> _order;

      public Comparer()
      {
        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "CS01",
            "CS10",
            "CS58",
            "CS11",
            "CS71",
            "CS02",
            "CS55",
            "CS03",
            "CS70",
            "CS54",
            "CS60",
                 //<---How to prioritize any value that is not predefined in list to show up here?  such as 1234-444-555
            "CS57",

        };

        _order = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
          _order.Add(list[i], i);
        }
      }

      public int Compare(string x, string y)
      {
        //If either string is less than 4 characters, return the comparsion of the two strings
        if (x.Length < 4 || y.Length < 4)
          return x.CompareTo(y);

        string xPrefix = x.Substring(0, 4);
        string yPrefix = y.Substring(0, 4);

        int xSequence;
        int ySequence;
        if (_order.TryGetValue(xPrefix, out xSequence)
            && _order.TryGetValue(yPrefix, out ySequence))
        {
          // If both X and Y are in dictionary, return the comparison of the two
          return xSequence.CompareTo(ySequence);
        }

        if (_order.TryGetValue(xPrefix, out xSequence))
        {
          // If only X is in dictionary, x > y
          return 1;
        }

        if (_order.TryGetValue(yPrefix, out ySequence))
        {
          // If only y is in dictionary, x < y 
          return -1;
        }

        // otherwise return the comparison of the two 
        return x.CompareTo(y);

      }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("(", "");
      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(")", "");
      string[] items = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      Array.Sort<string>(items, 0, items.Length, new Comparer());
      textBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);

    }
```

With the Input

```
9988777
CS01 
1234444
CS11
77888999
```

It outputs :

```
1234444
77888999 
9988777
CS01 
CS11
```

**One Major Pitfall here** - This wont sort items properly if you have an item in the list that is < 4 characters long - e.g. if you input 99 instead of 9988777 it wont work properly.

In order to solve that you need to clearly identify what type of input you will have.